# pause a single session but keep processing other

Tags: mysql, lua, mysql-proxy

I want to the `mysql-proxy lua` script to handle interleaving accesses to a website (e.g. two different browser windows/users) but being able to pause/delay one of the two without influencing the other.Handling sessions interleavingly is possible in `mysql-proyx lua` (so it seems regarding the later listed output) but as soon as I start delaying the script it blocks everything and the other session cannot advance either.

```
-- the query which indicates the session/connection that shall be delayed at that execution
local qoi = "SELECT loginattempts,uid FROM mybb_users WHERE username='user1' LIMIT 1"

function read_query(packet)
        if string.byte(packet) == proxy.COM_QUERY then
                query = packet:sub(2)
                start_time = os.time()
                if query == qoi then
                        print("busy wait")
                        while os.time() < start_time + 20 do
                                --nothing
                        end
                        print("busy wait end")
                end
                print("Connection id: " .. proxy.connection.server.thread_id)
        end
end
```

However this script ends up with output:

```
Connection id: 36
busy wait
busy wait end
Connection id: 36
Connection id: 36
Connection id: 36
Connection id: 37
Connection id: 37
Connection id: 36
Connection id: 36
Connection id: 36
Connection id: 37
```

and not the expected

```
Connection id: 36
busy wait
connection id: 37
connection id: 37
busy wait end
Connection id: 36
```

**Is my intention even achievable and if so how?**

Comment: @i486 I would appreciate a longer comment/answer. If my thinking is seriously flawed and my intention is not achievable an answer explaining exactly this would be as good as any. There is nothing out there covering this (potential) use-case and a definite answer would save the next poor soul trying to achieve this some time.

Comment: your program doesn't sleep, it's actually very busy running that empty while loop,

Comment: @Piglet I am aware of that, though given that lua does not support sleep a "busy wait" is all I got as far as I known. The overall intention is to delay that session/execution sufficiently to have other parallel executions interleave. I edited the offending section of my question.

Comment: but is the access not already interleaved? I mean your output shows ids 36,36,36, 37,37, 36, 36... or do you want to completely block one id while the other is busy?

Comment: @Piglet Yes exactly. I want to 'dictate' the point where interleaving is forced. Namely in between 'busy wait' and 'busy wait end'. I am aware that I cannot control interleaving completely but I want this point to be a forced point of interleaving. The second expected output is what I want to achieve.

Comment: I'd just execute queries of the wanted session (or the wanted type) and either queue or ignore anything else until I'm done with the preferred stuff. but I have no experience with that mysql-proxy thing. that's just a general approach to that problem.

Comment: @Piglet That would impede the application as queries are effectively dropped (or postponed, but this is what my question is essentially about) and change the mysql-proxy from being invisible to the application to having an impact on logic and execution flow. So this is not an option/would not be mysql-proxy anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be impossible to delay the session within lua but it works just as fine if I outsource the delay to mysql server as this will force the interleaving as well.

```
local DEBUG = true

local qoi = "SELECT loginattempts,uid FROM mybb_users WHERE username='user1' LIMIT 1"


function read_query(packet)
        ret = nil
        comp_query = qoi
        if string.byte(packet) == proxy.COM_QUERY then
                query = packet:sub(2)
                if query == comp_query then
                        if DEBUG then
                                print("found matching query " .. packet:sub(2))
                                print("insert sleep")
                        end
                        inj_query = "SELECT sleep(30);"
                        new_packet = string.char(proxy.COM_QUERY) .. inj_query
                        proxy.queries:append(1, new_packet, { resultset_is_needed = true })
                        proxy.queries:append(2, packet, { resultset_is_needed = true })
                        ret = proxy.PROXY_SEND_QUERY
                end
        end
        return ret
end


function read_query_result(inj)
        if inj.id == 1 then
                if DEBUG then
                        print("sleep query returns")
                end
                return proxy.PROXY_IGNORE_RESULT
        end
        if inj.id == 2 then
                if DEBUG then
                        print("regular query returns")
                end
                return 
        end
        return
end
```